# Caching JSON Arrays On Client

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking at this problem for a few days now and I simply don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  There appears to be a few problems with my code that I now simply cannot see the wood for the trees with this.  I've included the code below with some comments.

```
(function (myPage, $, undefined) {

    myPage.contextsArrays = [];
    myPage.currentContextsArray = [];

    myPage.getTags = function (event) {

        // try to resolve tags from local variable
        myPage.currentContextsArray = $.grep(myPage.contextsArrays, function (elm) { return elm.id == event.tagArea.Id; });

        if (myPage.currentContextsArray.length == 0) {

            $.getJSON('/exercises/getstrategycontexts/' + event.tagArea.Id, null, function (tags) {

                // despite 200 response codes from the server this doesn't ever get executed …
                myPage.contextsArrays.push({ id: event.tagArea.Id, items: tags });
                myPage.currentContextsArray = tags;

                alert(myPage.currentContextsArray);    
            });
        }

        $.get('/templates/strategycontextdc.html', function (template) {

            $('#tagHost').html('');
            $('#tagHostTitle').html('Tags - ' + event.tagArea.Text);

            // myPage.currentContextsArray is ALWAYS [ ]
            $.each(myPage.currentContextsArray, function (i, tag) {

                var html = Mustache.to_html(template, tag);
                $('#tagHost').append(html);
            });
        });
    };

}(window.myPage = window.myPage || {}, jQuery));
```

What I'm trying to do here is some basic caching of values in a local variable.  The tags are used in the UI to provide the user with a method of adding a score against a value.

I only ever want to request a collection of tags from the server if they haven't already been requested and stored in the local variable.

What I'm not understanding is that the $.getJSON() is executed (a request is made and a 200 code received along with the data) but the callback function is never executed so my collections of tags are never stored in the array for later retrieval nor set in the variable of current tags for use immediately in the UI (and therefore also consequently can never be resolved if re-requested).

I've used this jQuery command a lot and I cannot see why this isn't ever executed in this scenario.  I can't see the problem with the code basically.

I've tried everything I can think of (I'm still very new to JS really) and I've exhausted my knowledge on why this code simply doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't get executed? The way you are doing it now it just might be that your `$.get`'s callback is executed before the `$.getJSON`'s one. Have you tried nesting the `$.get` inside the other callback or kicking off the templating in the other callback?

Comment: I did originally have them nested and that was working but I couldn't figure out how to conditionally check the local variable for a cached version of the tags without executing the `$get.JSON` call I'm trying to avoid making needlessly.

Comment: But would it (maintaining a fix order of calls) fix your problem? You could make use of `$.Deferred`s if you want to restrict AJAXing to only when necessary.

Comment: I'm sure it would as I've had this code working without attempting the caching local variable idea.  I've not even come across $.Deferred  before so I'll go have a read and see what that offers.

Comment: The problem is that i need to cache the tags and their values in order to make the current screen I'm working on actually function properly.  I really don't know how to make this work if I'm honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your AJAX calls' callbacks fire in the correct order (as one of them relies on the other's result). You could use the `jqXHR`-object's `promise`-interface for that:

```
(function (myPage, $, undefined) {

    myPage.contextsArrays = [];
    myPage.currentContextsArray = [];

    myPage.getTags = function (event) {

        // try to resolve tags from local variable
        myPage.currentContextsArray = $.grep(myPage.contextsArrays, function (elm) { return elm.id == event.tagArea.Id; });

        var dfd; //this is where we'll store either the AJAX call's promise when we need to wait for the AJAX call to finish or simply store true if we don't

        if (!myPage.currentContextsArray.length) {

            dfd = $.getJSON('/exercises/getstrategycontexts/' + event.tagArea.Id, null, function (tags) {

                // despite 200 response codes from the server this doesn't ever get executed …
                myPage.contextsArrays.push({ id: event.tagArea.Id, items: tags });
                myPage.currentContextsArray = tags;

                alert(myPage.currentContextsArray);    

            }).promise();

        } else {

            dfd = true;

        }

        $.when(dfd).then(function(){ // $.when will either wait for the passed promise's resolve or immediately execute the function passed to then() when passed true

            $.get('/templates/strategycontextdc.html', function (template) {

                $('#tagHost').html('');
                $('#tagHostTitle').html('Tags - ' + event.tagArea.Text);

                // myPage.currentContextsArray is ALWAYS [ ]
                $.each(myPage.currentContextsArray, function (i, tag) {

                    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, tag);
                    $('#tagHost').append(html);
                });
            });
        });
    };

}(window.myPage = window.myPage || {}, jQuery));
```

Read more about **[promise()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)**

Comment: Wow ... ok, a LOT to take in there.  Really appreciate this m90, will incorporate this into my code and see how I get on.  Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks chap. All incorporated and working perfectly on first test. Thank you!